# Divisibility by 8 when converted in base 10

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

How many 7-digit numbers are there in binary(base-2)? How many of them are divisible by 8 when converted to base 10?

My approach:

In binary system, only two digits are there i.e. 0 and 1. So except for the first place, all the renaming 7 places can be filled by either 0 or 1. As first one can't be zero so it can be filled in only one way.
So. 1x2x2x2x2x2x2 = 64

Now, I don't know how to approach the second part, please assist in same.

Answer for second part is 8.

Comment: Numbers are divisible by 8 regardless of whether they are converted to base 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: $8$ in base two is $1000$. The base two numbers divisible by $8,$ then, will be the numbers that end in what three digits? This makes for an easy generalization to any given number of digits (not just $7$) and any integer power of a given base (not just the third power of two).

P.S.: Conversion to base $10$ changes nothing.

Comment: Got it. So it should be 1x2x2x2x1x1x1 = 8
As last three digits have to be zero, so these can be filled in only one way. Thanks

Comment: Bingo! Well done.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: what is the 'least' seven-digit binary number (expressed in base 10), and what is the greatest? Every number in between is expressible as a 7-digit binary number. All that remains is to determine which among these numbers are divisible by 8.

Comment: Haha, I do tend to get a bit too excited when it comes to these things. Thanks, edited for clarity. :)

Comment: No problem. I understand your excitement perfectly. (My students, on the other hand....)

Comment: Got it, least and greatest > 64 and 127 I guess.
so [(120-64)/8]+1 = 8 numbers in all
thanks.

Comment: Yup, absolutely! Glad to help. Of course, Cameron's answer is a bit more instructive and general.